# Bed room light switch

Tags: electrical

After going to bed a few hours into sleep light would come on in the off position.. this happened a few times. I replaced switch and last night while in the on position it turned off cycled the switch a few times wouldn’t come back on… left it off overnight… stayed off .. turned on this am and it came on..so what could be happening?

Comment: Common problem is usually loose wire connections or bulb connection if light does not come on.

Comment: Cc coming on when switch is in the office position is harder to explain. That could be failing switch, could be short circuit past the switch, or could be something like a three-way circuit with someone throwing the other switch... Though it's unusual for bedrooms with one door to have three-way switches.

Comment: Ok I checked and it still had cfl bulbs so after changing switch and lights go out in on position so they may have gotten hot so replaced with led … so will see thanks dc